# Web page element responsive to currently shown section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm dividing my web page in several sections (let's say section1, section2, etc.) so I can access to them from the main menu, using the corresponding href="#section1", href="#section2", etc.

This menu is actually a "floating menu", meaning that it's always shown at the top, even when you scroll down on the page. I'd like to make the menu's buttons responsive to the section that is being shown at each moment. For example, if I'm looking at "section2", I'd like the "section2" button to be coloured in a different way, or with bold letter...

I guees this is not really difficult, but it seems to me really hard to find about it.
Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This functionality is commonly referred to as a "Scrollspy". [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) has a plugin for that, and there are multiple [jquery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/scrollspy/) which do the job too. If you want to DIY it, you need to watch the document's scrollTop value and check if it's past the top of each of our sections.

Answer (score 1):

> If You are using Bootstrap library.
>
> It in build provides the option for selection of the button.
>
> Plain HTML if you have used then you can use Javascript or JQuery library for button to be Selected with differnt CSS.

http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/

> Button API can be used to select the button and change the CSS for the same.